# Rails geocoder gem | Google API error: over query limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, rails-geocoder

I know there are others questions with the same problem but i don't find the solution in them. 
In my rails project(it is in development) when i try to send address for the first time at day the geocoder don't search lat and long. 
In the terminal i'm receive the message: Google API error: over query limit.
I did not reach the google query limit per/hour, per/day and don't know how resolve this.

Comment: You need to cache lookups or otherwise optimize your app to hit the API less. Check this out => (https://github.com/codeforamerica/ohana-api/wiki/Customizing-the-geocoding-configuration)

Comment: Thanks, this work!
But i need change => REDIS = Redis.connect(url: ENV['REDISTOGO_URL'])  
To =>REDIS = Redis.new(url: ENV['REDISTOGO_URL'])

Comment: Awesome happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

The limit is frequently by IP. Are you running your app on shared infrastructure (such as Heroku)? You could also try geocoding client-side, which uses the user's IP as opposed to your server's.

Comment: My app is in development, i trying test this in localhost.

Comment: locally don't save lat and long. I receive message:" Google API error: over query limit" in my first query of day

Comment: @srt32 there is no shared server locally. Also on Heroku you don't share IP address on the shared server.

Comment: @Cyzanfar sure they do. Check out https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quotaguard, which explicitly mentions the geocoding use case

Comment: @LéoRocha are you on some non-personal local IP address? For example, are you in a coffee shop in a city or using a VPN? If you are, other usage of the geocoding API could be counting against your limit if your IP is not unique to you.

Comment: @srt32 I'm home, i think that doesnt the problem

Comment: @LéoRocha did you figure out your issue? Are you using an API key?